# "Full Time Employee versus Contract Work?" on SO should have been migrated here instead of deleted

Tags: discussion, migration, deleted-questions

I've been a long time SO and stack user in general. I'm REALLY disappointed that [Full Time Employee versus Contract Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201088/302677) on SO was deleted instead of migrated to Programmers. I don't care about the rep, I care about the answers. That one really mattered to me.

I see that "career advice" is on the don't list, but questions about "freelancing and business concerns" are good. I very much think this question should be allowed.

Freelancing and contracting have massive overlaps. What does "freelancing and business concerns" even mean if this kind of extremely useful question is not allowed? I can see rejecting specific career advice (simply under the too localized reason), but this was VERY close to being **specifically about the business concerns of freelancing**.

**EDIT** After seeing a screen capture of that question again (I was going off memory before) I can see Bill's objection that it's not unique enough to programming. I remembered a heavier emphasis on IP concerns, which to me can be much more unique to the software field. It's been suggested that I try to clean it up and resubmit it... I'd feel odd about asking a question and immediately supplying my own answer, but if that's what it takes...  :)

Comment: Not a bad question, however the way it is currently written would not be suitable for our site. The answer was pretty decent though. Perhaps you should consider reposting a better-written version of the question, and answer it yourself with a summary of what the answers there contain.

Comment: @Rachel: I will certainly put this on my todo list. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Please take this up with the Stack Overflow moderators.

There's nothing we can do at this end.

**UPDATE**

After further reflection I don't think that that specific question should be migrated. It's old and the question isn't sufficiently unique to software developers for it to be 100% on topic here.

Search Programmers for any similar questions and if there aren't any that address your specific concerns then please ask a new question.

Comment: Just as a question, does it sound like something that would fit? I know it's hard to tell without seeing it, and I'm a little fuzzy myself (although I'm certain it could be reworded if needed)

Comment: @darron - I'm in two minds. I think it would depend on the quality of answers it attracted. If it started getting a lot of one liners and/or link only answers I'd have to close it as not constructive

Comment: @darron - I have to apologise - I didn't check the link and had I done so I would have realised it was an old question. I strongly believe that old questions should **not** be migrated.

Comment: Why's that? When the alternative is deletion? I can see 'locked' for historical reasons, but if it's going to be deleted...

Comment: @darron - these things are being discussed.

Comment: off this specific question, and on the more general deletion of historical content... I can say as a strong advocate of Stack sites that this feels like rewriting history and a violation of people's enthusiastic contributions to the site. Delete this stuff early, not after they've got history. If they're cluttering up the lists, give them a flag that artificially lowers their ranking (preferably) or has them only show up in search (not so preferably).

Comment: @darron - that's part of what's being discussed. However, as I'm not a moderator on SO I can only really shout from the side lines.

Comment: There's no way we'd migrate that unless a moderator here specifically requested it. It's from 2008, it's been answered to death and has an accepted answer and the 'programming' part of the question could be substituted with any other profession. That's just not the kind of question we [moderators] want to send to a sister site. It could probably be edited to better meet the six subjective guidelines (and PSE FAQ), but we come back to the fact that it was asked in 2008 and has an accepted answer. (I'm a mod on SO)